# ListSelectionEvent, firing an event when clicking the currently selected item in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listselectionlistener

Let 'x' be an item in the JList. When I click it for the first time, the event fires, when I click it again, the event does not fire. I have to click some other item and then come back to 'x'.

How can I fire the event repeatedly from 'x' without having to deal with other items.

This is my code:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {

       if (list.getSelectedIndex() == -1) {} else {
            String clicked = (String)list.getSelectedValue();



            //method to fire is here

        }
    }
    updateDisplays();

}
```

Comment: You can add a `MouseListener` and watch for clicks. Note that a click that changes the selection will fire both the `MouseListener` and your `ListSelectionListener`. It seems like sort of an unusual UX decision, though, to assign significance to a click on an already selected item in a list. What are you trying to do?

Comment: *"How can I fire the event repeatedly from 'x'.."*  ..why would you need to fire it repeatedly?  This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).  What *actual feature* are you trying to implement?

Comment: I'm creating a JList of commands that the user inputs. The JList tracks the previous commands of the user so if the user wants to repeat a command, they should be able to click on it from the JList. @JasonC

Comment: @user3184240 That makes sense. Your best bet then is to add a `MouseListener`; although I recommend looking for double-clicks instead of single-clicks if the click is going to execute an action (especially if the action changes data and is not undoable). Also note that your `ListSelectionListener` will execute actions as you navigate through the list with the keyboard, which may not be what you intend.

Comment: suggestion as answers here coming wrong way, carefully because by using MosueWhatever you lost interaction from KeyEvents, then you lost those events, there no issue to test if value changed as is showing in your code snipped (this listener firing twice - alyways)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ListSelectionListener` reflects changes to the lists selection, you could use a `MouseListener` instead...

For example...

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(evt) && evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
                int index = list.locationToIndex(evt.getPoint());
                System.out.println("You clicked item  @ " + index);
            }
        }
    }
}

list.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `MouseListener` and watch for clicks. Note that a click that changes the selection will fire both the `MouseListener` and your `ListSelectionListener`.

Another option is to immediately clear the selection from your `ListSelectionListener`; that way the next click will reselect and retrigger, although you will lose the ability to navigate through items with the keyboard.

It seems like sort of an unusual UX decision, though, to assign significance to a click on an already selected item in a list.

Adding based on your question comments: If you go the `MouseListener` route, I recommend looking for double-clicks instead of single-clicks if the click is going to execute an action (especially if the action changes data and is not undoable). Also note that your `ListSelectionListener` will execute actions as you navigate through the list with the keyboard, which may not be what you intend.

If your commands in your history list are *typed*, you could also consider using a drop-down combo box for both command entry *and* the history list, where a selection from history fills in the command text but does not execute. You'd also have an opportunity to add auto-complete from command history.